# form.ShowDialog(owner) throws IndexOutOfRangeException possibly causes?

Tags: c#, forms, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a (fairly complex) application and in certain rare situations (specifically the first time a certain button is pressed) the function

```
    public static bool ShowDialogOk(this Form form, IWin32Window owner = null) {
            return form.ShowDialog(owner) == DialogResult.OK;
```

throw the exception

```
{System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index -1 does not have a value.
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
```

Now this function is called with the same variables quite a few times before the crash making it hard for me to tell what is wrong. Does anybody know the possible causes of the IndexOutOfRangeException in the form.ShowDialog function? That way I might be able to debug this code a bit better.

Edit: I noticed that the ShowDialogOk is called from only 1 place where if I put a breakpoint on this line it is passed only when creating the GUI but not actually when the error triggers.

Comment: And before anybody asks yes I know that the index out of bounds exception means that I' m going out of the index bounds (but I cannot really change the windows.Forms code). I'm looking for possible situations that can cause this error in the windows.forms. Earlier calls use the same form in at least the shallow copy but giving the code of the entire gui would be to large for this question.

Comment: The StackTrace tells me that the problem is with your `DataGridView`. Are you adding something when the form opens? Are you forcing a MouseClick? I don't think the code you show is the cause of the problem.

Comment: The code isn't forcing a mouseclick but is responding to a mouseclick here.

Comment: Your question is both too general and specific at the same time. It is too general because the reason why `form.ShowDialog` "throws an exception" is because some code executing inside the form threw an exception that wasn't handled, and this bubbled up to the ShowDialog method. The problem, however, is not *in* or *with* the call to ShowDialog, but rather with the code that threw the exception. In this case it is the DataGridView that has a problem. You should clean up your question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ok so my question is how do I find where this code is going wrong. Somewhere inside the datagridview an exception is occurring but that is still not code I wrote.I' m looking for some method or hints towards what might be wrong there.

Comment: Well then you have to show more code. I'd bet that the problem is an event firing when you click on a cell. My guess: the `SelectedIndex` of your `DataGridView` is -1. Then the you try to get the item with this index from your `CurrencyManager` (`List`, `Array`,...) which is obviously not working.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih well I added a breakpoint on the onclick and that wasn't actually activating until after the exception was already thrown. The CurrencyManager  is not actually under my control as it' s inside the windows forms. The error chain is click => exception => on click

Comment: Have you fed the datagridview data? Can you show all the properties you set on this object in the designer, as well as in the constructor of the form?

Comment: Yes the datagridview is fed data by from a list             .        public void setDataSource(List<NavigationInfo> data)
        {
            this.DistanceRulesDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.DistanceRulesDataGrid.DataSource = null;
            this.DistanceRulesDataGrid.DataSource = data;;
            this.DistanceRulesDataGrid.SelectAll();

        }

Answer (score -1):

Just where CurrencyManager property is and do a size check. (it is a property in the form class, and its probably used in an grid event (row enter or somrthing)) (assume it is a property because:CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index))

```
var index = <somenumber>;
if(CurrencyManager.Length > 0 && index < CurrencyManager.Length) //also can be Count()
   CurrencyManager[index]
else
   // Do some logic when index is out of bounds.
```

Comment: The problem is that the words CurrencyManager don' t appear anywhere in my code. What's going on is that a problem occurs somewhere inside of the windows.forms and I can't really access there.

Comment: Take out, delete, comment, any format on currency in that form and see if it works. (its just temporary)

Comment: Yhea I tried that problem is that the form in question is really just a datagridview with a list of buttons in it where right now one new button appears every button press, the first time I press the initial button it throws this error.

Comment: You check see that when using that kind of stuff in WindowsForm there are lots of checks for sizes and lengths.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx

There are two ways to debug this. 1) understand all the code and see why is failing. 2) start commenting out parts and see where it fails.

Comment: True, but the idea is the same. I will add CurrencyManager.Length > 0
Thanks!

Comment: Let's not forget that the CurrencyManager has to be thread safe and as such it's possible for the length to change while inside this function.